# Partitioning my new system

Tags: partitioning

I have recently built a new computer and have  500GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I am having trouble deciding how to partition my space. Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you really have 500**MB** SSD or more of a 500**GB** SSD?

Comment: 500GB it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another answer:

I have similar configuration (500GB SSD and 2TB HDD).

I have one file system for each disk (both are encrypted).

The SSD has the OS, plus /home. The HDD has directories with all the bulky stuff: music, photos, and plenty of rather large VM images. There are soft links from the SSD tree to the HDD contents where necessary.

In the past I used to be partition-happy, but this leads to a lot of wasted disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do swap,root,and home partitions. If you have a good amount of memory, you probably won't need a swap partition most of the time, but the rare time you run out of memory it could slow you down to a crawl. The old recommendation was to use the same amount of swap as your memory, but if you've got plenty of ram then less should be okay. For root, I usually make that partition 20-30 gigs. I've only used about 5 right now (of my 30GB root) but I don't install a lot of big programs. Then make the home partition as big as you need (save space for more partitions if you want to dual boot with another distro).

Answer (score 0):

500 MB means 500 GB?

- Take 200 GB for the system on the ssd.

  - Create no swap partition
    (depends on the ram size, not more than 8 GB swap partition, mostly
    unused).
  - The rest of the ssd use for programms and backups of
    important files on the hdd.
- Store the data on the hdd.
- /tmp should be on a ramdisk to reduce write operations on the ssd.

I think there is no generally correct answer.

Comment: This is no one correct answer. I have multiple / (root) partitions of 25GB each on my SSD, but it is not fully allocated, yet. And a large data partition with another install or two on HDD, but it also is not fully allocated yet. Every user has there own needs. Even my own optimal partitioning of a few years ago, has now changed.

Comment: "This is no one correct answer." Why? Using 200 GB is because some data in the home dir and software installed on linux. May contain wine including big software. A SSD is not the best way to store data so the rest of the SSD should be used for more software or data that has accessed very fast or as backup because of redundancy. The HDD is the best store for long term data. The question owner did not say something about dual boot or something like that. Of cause I would take 200 GB Linux and 300 GB Windows on the SSD and split the HDD with EXT4 and NTFS.

Comment: With "I think there is no generally correct answer." I mean "Every user has there own needs." ;-)